# Displaying a value from a JSON array to a table in HTML5

Tags: angularjs, html, csv

I am doing a function of reading a content of csv file (test.csv) and store it in a variable (dataArray) and I have to display the values in this dataArray as a table in HTML5. I move those values from `dataArray` to `$scope.sushi` and created a HTML table with this variable but the data is not displaying in a table.

app.js:

```
    $.get("test.csv").then(function(data) {
            //window.alert($scope.rowSplit(data,"#"));
            var rows = data.split("\r\n");
            // var array = string.split('#');
            // window.alert("Rows"+rows[0]);
            window.alert("inside datasplit"+rows[1]);
            if(rows.length > 0){
                var firstRowCells = rows[0].split(",");
                var dataArray = new Array();
                for (var i=1; i < rows.length; i++)
                {
                    var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                     var obj = {};
                    for(var j=0; j < cells.length; j++)
                    {
                        obj[firstRowCells[j]] = cells[j];
                    }
                    dataArray.push(obj);
                }

                    //window.alert(dataArray);
                    $scope.sushi=dataArray;
              // window.alert("$scope.sushi*********************8"+JSON.stringify($scope.sushi));
            } 

html file sampletableangular.html

        <div class="container">
      <form> 
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="searchcon">
          </div>      
        </div>
      </form> 
        <div id="exportdata">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped tablelink">

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'issueno'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                issue no
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'issueno' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'issueno' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'dateassigned'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              date assigned
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'dateassigned' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'dateassigned' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'assignedby'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              assigned by
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'assignedby' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'assignedby' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'description'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              description
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'description' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'description' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'priority'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              priority
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'priority' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'priority' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'targetdate'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              target date
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'targetdate' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'targetdate' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'status'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              status
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'status' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'status' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'attachment'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
              attachment
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'attachment' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'attachment' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchcon">
            <td ng-click="display(roll.issueno);"><a href="#">{{ roll.issueno }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ roll.dateassigned }}</td>
            <td>{{ roll.assignedby }}</td>
            <td>{{ roll.description}}</td>
            <td>{{ roll.priority}}</td>
            <td>{{ roll.targetdate}}</td>
            <td>{{ roll.status}}</td>
            <td>{{ roll.attachment}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table> 
      </div>

and the contents in test.csv:

issue no ,date assigned ,assigned by ,description ,priority ,target date ,status ,attachment
1001,1/24/2015,TE_002,Dev,1,3/4/2016,pending,file1
1002,2/20/2016,TE_002,Dev,1,3/4/2016,pending,file52
1003,4/5/2016,SD_003,Des,2,3/1/2016,pending,file4
1004,2/1/2016,TE_002,Test,1,5/19/2016,completed,file23
1005,8/27/2016,TL_001,Des,3,12/18/2016,pending,file41
1006,10/16/2016,TE_002,Dev,3,10/25/2016,completed,file35
1007,7/13/2016,TE_003,Test,5,8/7/2016,pending,file12
```

I have to display the value in a csv file as a table in HTML using `$scope.sushi` variable.

Comment: any errors in console

Comment: Is it whole HTML code, or just a part of it?

Comment: it is just a table div

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing jQuery and Angular.

You make the request with jQuery `$.get("test.csv")`, then update the angular `$scope`. When you do this angular doesn't notice the change.

Try wrapping the $scope update with apply to force the angular digest:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.sushi=dataArray;
});
```

Or use the angular [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to make the request.